# Using SQL Replication, will records that are deleted in an article on the publisher be deleted on the subscriber too?

Tags: database-replication

I'm considering the use of SQL Replication for a requirement my client has to move data from an OLTP database (publisher) to a reporting database (subscriber).  However, every month data older than 2 years gets deleted from the OLTP database.  If I use SQL Replication, will this deletion of records from the OLTP database mean that the corresponding records will then be deleted from the Reporting database as well?  If so, is there a way to prevent this from happening?  You see, my client needs the Reporting database to retain all the data older than 2 years even once it has been deleted from the OLTP database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup it turns out that for each article (database table) that gets added to the publication, one can set whether deletes need to be sync'd.